# Certificate in Hyperledger

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to understand the Hyperledger Fabric infrastructure. I have couple of question.

(1) Why they have certificates for every block of their architecture and what the role of these certificates.

(2) How will you bind peers to orderer in the `crypto-config.yaml`

```
OrdererOrgs:
     Name: Orderer
     Domain: example.com
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer`
    PeerOrgs:
      Name: Org1
      Domain: org1.example.com
```

(3) Does orderer or peer communicate with external network over the chain?

Answer (score 1):

1. We don't have certificates for every block in the architecture.. not sure what you mean? The blocks are signed by orderer nodes, and the signature needs to be evaluated somehow, so the certificate of the orderer is put inside the block, in order for peers to verify it.
2. What does binding mean?
3. What do you mean communicate with external network?